# How to change default ulimit values in Mac OS X 10.6?

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, ulimit

Mac OS X limits number of processes to 266 and open files to 256. Sometimes this is problem; 256 open files and 266 processes aren't that much.

**How it's possible to change default ulimit values in Mac OS X 10.6.7?**

(Hopefully there's no difference between 10.6.7 and other Snow Leopard releases.)

[Related question](https://serverfault.com/questions/15564/where-are-the-default-ulimits-specified-on-os-x-10-5) in serverfault. Unfortunately, answer is for Mac OS X 10.5, and it's not working in 10.6.

Comment: For a quick change: `ulimit -n 1024`. But it doesn't change the default.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

launchctl has control over that now.

You can do a

```
launchctl limit maxfiles 2048 2048
```

to set the soft and hard limits for maximum files open. For more information see the 'limit' section of:

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/launchctl.1.html

Comment: This still works in OS X 10.9

Comment: I'm running 10.9.4 and when I `launchctl limit maxfiles 2048 2048` and `mongo` I'm still getting the `soft rlimits too low` error. Anything else I can try?

Comment: after changing the limit with sudo launchctl etc., then close/open the terminal and set the ulimit -n 2048. this time it should work. check it with ulimit -n

Comment: I ran this command and it did something to my Mac. Is it possible to return it to the former setting?

Comment: Could someone confirm if 'maxfiles 266 256' will return it to the default?

Comment: After doing 'launchctl limit maxfiles 2048 2048' I got 'too many open files' on my Mac when I tried to do anything in the shell, and Cocoa apps showed empty menus. System was pretty much toasted. A reboot thankfully fixed it.

Comment: Do not run this command on macOS Sierra. The correct command would be `launchctl limit maxfiles 2048 unlimited` though I would suggest viewing your current settings with `launchctl limit maxfiles` before doing so, else you'll completely lock up your computer.

Comment: @snowe2010 When I run `launchctl limit maxfiles` the console outputs:  `maxfiles    256            unlimited`  Given this output, would it be safe to run `launchctl limit maxfiles 2048 unlimited` ?

Comment: @Kelseydh I am not sure. I wrote that comment almost 3 years ago and do not even remember why haha. Maybe just make sure you have all files saved and programs closed before doing so.

Comment: I wish I had read the comments before running this command... DO NOT RUN `launchctl limit maxfiles 2048 2048`, it will freeze your computer (Catalina 10.15)!

Answer (score 9):

There's an answer on StackOverflow for this one. Apparently [`ulimit`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1364955/python-on-snow-leopard-how-to-open-255-sockets/1365014#1365014) does it now.

Comment: You can change values with ulimit, but it's not saving those. Linked post do not include any way to save defaults.

Comment: A quick fix: Edit your ~/.bash_profile and add this on a line:
ulimit -n 1024
(using whatever number you like, of course)

Comment: @PapaFreud That's only executed when you open the terminal/bash. Not all programs are executed from terminal.

Answer (score 3):

As @snowe2010 said in a comment, the correct command for Sierra+ would be:

`launchctl limit maxfiles 2048 unlimited`

Answer (score 1):

FYI.

`.bash_profile` update didn't help me for OS v10.10.3, but reinstallation NodeJS from 0.10.35 to 0.12.3 helped me, and error disappear.